# How to skip arguments when their default is desired

Tags: php

If I have a function like this:

```
function abc($a,$b,$c = 'foo',$d = 'bar') { ... }
```

And I want `$c` to assume it's default value, but need to set `$d`, how would I go about making that call in PHP?

Comment: In PHP 8, you can skip parameters
Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73548535/14193006

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PHP can't do this, unfortunately. You could work around this by checking for null. For example:

```
function abc($a, $b, $c = 'foo', $d = 'bar') {
    if ($c === null)
        $c = 'foo';
    // Do something...
}
```

Then you'd call the function like this:

```
abc('a', 'b', null, 'd');
```

No, it's not exactly pretty, but it does the job. If you're feeling really adventurous, you could pass in an associative array instead of the last two arguments, but I think that's way more work than you want it to be.

Comment: +1 Nice work around. I'd probably leave out the $='foo' part in the signature since the null check handles the default now.

Comment: True, but what if you want to omit both `$c` and `$d`? It would now throw an error because the function has 3 required arguments.

Comment: The problem is that my functions have 5+ vars. This is for a system for possible future people who aren't PHP savvy to manipulate the code by setting specific variables.

Comment: Like I said, there's no other way to do this. You could, like I mentioned, pass an associative array into the function and just set any unset values to their defaults. But otherwise, you're out of luck; sorry.

Comment: I use Syntactic and it's awesome https://github.com/topclaudy/php-syntactic

Answer (score 4):

Associative arrays aren't so bad here, especially when the argument list starts getting bigger:

```
function abc($args = array()) {
    $defaults = array('c' => 'foo', 'd' => 'bar');
    $args = array_merge($defaults, $args);
}
```

If you wanted to explicitly make some of them required, you could put them in front:

```
function abc($a, $b, $args = array()) {

}
```

It's up to you, I've seen big projects use both approaches (forcing passing null and this) and I honestly sort of prefer this one. If you are familiar with Javascript a lot of scripts take use of this behavior when you pass options to them, so it's not completely foreign.

Answer (score 3):

PHP doesn't support this. ([non-explicit ref](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default))

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can do this in php.

Answer (score 0):

What if you put all your parameters into an argument object and then parse that?

```
function abc(arguments) {
  foreach (index=>value in arguments) { ... }
}
abc({message: "Out of condoms.", haveSex: false, code: 404});
```