# Retain Delimiters when Splitting String

Tags: php, regex, explode, preg-split

Edit: OK, I can't read, thanks to Col. Shrapnel for the help. If anyone comes here looking for the same thing to be answered...
`print_r(preg_split('/([\!|\?|\.|\!\?])/', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));`

Is there any way to split a string on a set of delimiters, and retain the position and character(s) of the delimiter after the split?

For example, using delimiters of `!`  `?`  `.`  `!?`  turning this:

```
$string = 'Hello. A question? How strange! Maybe even surreal!? Who knows.';
```

into this

```
array('Hello', '.', 'A question', '?', 'How strange', '!', 'Maybe even surreal', '!?', 'Who knows', '.');
```

Currently I'm trying to use `print_r(preg_split('/([\!|\?|\.|\!\?])/', $string));` to capture the delimiters as a subpattern, but I'm not having much luck.

Comment: why not to read the function's manual page? may be there can be an answer? though to catch delimiters as a subpattern you can use preg_match_all. but split is the best for sure. just make a habit to refer to the man page first

Comment: Erp. Just gone back over the page, and I'm off to the opticians for a set of glasses now :/ I'm going blind.

Thanks for making me look at that again :P

Comment: Note that you’re using a character class. `[\!|\?|\.|\!\?]` means ony of the characters `!`, `|`, `?`, and `.`. What you probably want is this: `(!|\?|\.|!\?)`. Or with a character class: `([?.]|!\??)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment sounds like you've found the relevant flag, but your regex was a little off, so I'm going to add this anyway:

```
preg_split('/(!\?|[!?.])/', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Note that this will leave spaces at the beginning of every string after the first, so you'll probably want to run them all through `trim()` as well.

Results:

```
$string = 'Hello. A question? How strange! Maybe even surreal!? Who knows.';
print_r(preg_split('/(!\?|[!?.])/', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => .
    [2] =>  A question
    [3] => ?
    [4] =>  How strange
    [5] => !
    [6] =>  Maybe even surreal
    [7] => !?
    [8] =>  Who knows
    [9] => .
    [10] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

From PHP8.1, it is no longer permitted to use `null` as the limit parameter for `preg_split()` because an integer is expected. When seeking unlimited output elements from the return value, it is acceptable to use `0` or `-1`. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/LioCd))

To avoid empty elements in the returned array, I recommend `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` as an additional flag. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/mrIgM))

```
var_export(
    preg_split(
        '/(!\?|[!?.])/',
        $string,
        0,
        PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
    )
);
```

Since PHP8, it is technically possible to omit the limit parameter and declare flags by using [named parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64997399/2943403).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the  PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE  to the preg_split function:

```
$str = 'Hello. A question? How strange!';
$var = preg_split('/([!?.])/', $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$var = array(
    0 => "Hello",
    1 => ".",
    2 => " A question",
    3 => "?",
    4 => " How strange",
    5 => "!",
    6 => "",
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also split on the space after a `.`, `!`, `?` or `!?`. But this can only be used if you can guarantee that there is a space after such a character.

You can do this, by matching a  but with a positive look-back: `(<=\.|!?|?|!)`: this makes the regex

```
'/(?<=\.|\?|!) /'
```

And then, you'll have to check if the strings matched ends with `!?`: if so, substring the last two. If not, you'll have to substring the last character.