# Passing parameter to a function by parameter name?

Tags: php, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [named PHP optional arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342908/named-php-optional-arguments)

Is it possible in PHP to pass parameters directly, for example if I have a function:

```
function test ($a="",$b="",$c=""){}
```

is it possible to call the function with only $c parameter, now I am doing this by passing all parameters:

```
test("","","Hello");
```

but can I do this like

```
test($c="Hello");
```

?