# Pass values to specific arguments in PHP

Tags: php, function, arguments

If I have a function such as

```
function foo($a, $b = 2, $c = 3)
{
  return [$a, $b, $c];
}
```

Then I can omit passing `$b` and $c since they have default values. But, say, I want to pass something to `$c`, but not to `$b`. How can I do it? Obviously I could swap their places in the declaration (`function foo($a, $c = 3, $b = 2`), but then I wouldn't be able to only pass `$b`.

My point is that I want to make a function that has arguments with default values, but which ones I want to pass varies. I tried this: `print_r(foo(1, $c = 5))`, but it results in `[1, 5, 3]` not in `[1, 2, 5]`.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342908/named-php-optional-arguments

Comment: You can't skip the second parameter. If you need to pass the third parameter you *must* pass the correct value for the second paramter.

Comment: Not possible. What I do is : `foo($param1, 2, $param3)` i.e. preserve the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does not support named parameters. 
You can use only ordered parameters  with proper  valued in right position

eg

```
foo( $a, 4 , 3);
```

or eventually unassigned  value became null in related  vars

```
   foo( $a,  null , 3);
```

result

```
 esults in [1, null, 3]
```

Comment: This is incorrect. NULL will become the second value in that array. https://3v4l.org/TvvQP

Comment: Okay, thanks. This looks hideous, but that's not the only un-aesthetical thing in php, I guess.

Comment: @JohnConde   cirrect answer updated

Comment: Still incorrect: https://3v4l.org/vHQoe