# Issue with php7 functions with default argument values

Tags: php, function, arguments

As I am updating my script, there is some issues appearing I don't know if because of new php version or it was there all along but I haven't noticed yet. Here is one generic example that got me a lot of troubles:

```
function doSomething(arg1, arg2="test", arg3="error") { ... }
// so I did run some tests...
doSomething("Hi"); arg1, arg2, arg3 will be "Hi", "test", "error"
doSomething("Hi", "again"); arg1, arg2, arg3 will be "Hi", "again", "error"
doSomething("Hi", NULL, "no error"); arg1, arg2, arg3 will be "Hi", NULL, "noerror"
doSomething("Hi", FALSE, "no error"); arg1, arg2, arg3 will be "Hi", FALSE, "noerror"
```

The default value is only passed if I leave the argument empty at all. But if I wish to leave arg2 empty to get the default? Is there some keyword for this or some workaround?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64997399/5947043

Comment: Thought I am 11 years late! So PHP 8 has a solution, until PHP 7 there is no workaround but to define diferently de function itself. I am wondering if my question is duplicated or is complementing the old one...

Comment: I'd say it's pretty much an exact duplicate.