# Create insert function in php

Tags: php, sql, function

Hello so I have a logs table in my database and in every user action like log in, log out, edit, delete, create, I want it to be logged. Here is my current code in every action:

```
    $action = "Log in"; //if user log in
    $query = "INSERT INTO tbllogs 
            (logorigin, 
             logaction, 
             loguser, 
             logdate, 
             logoutcome) 
              VALUES
            (:origin, 
             :action, 
             :user, 
             :dt, 
             :outcome)";

              $stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
              $stmt->bindParam(':origin', $ip);
              $stmt->bindParam(':action', $action);
              $stmt->bindParam(':user', $_SESSION['id']);
              $stmt->bindParam(':dt', $dateTime);
              $stmt->bindParam(':outcome', $outcome);
              $stmt->execute();
```

What I wanted to do is instead of repeating this code in every user action, I want to create a function that will do like this. But my problem is, I am using different values in my `$action` variable like for example if the user will log in, `$action = "Log in"`, if the user logs out, `$action = "Log out"`. How can I accomplish that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following function in a file and include it on every page where you want to Log the activity. And then call the function with variable as follows:

`logging('Log In',$ip,$outcome);`

```
function logging($action=null,$ip,$outcome){
    $query = "INSERT INTO tbllogs (logOrigin, logAction, logUser, logDate, logOutcome) VALUES (:origin, :action, :user, :dt, :outcome)";
              $stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
              $stmt->bindParam(':origin', $ip);
              $stmt->bindParam(':action', $action);
              $stmt->bindParam(':user', $_SESSION['id']);
              $stmt->bindParam(':dt', $dateTime);
              $stmt->bindParam(':outcome', $outcome);
              $stmt->execute();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @tiGer yes array can be used but there are only three values so I haven't used.

Comment: Hello, should I include my database configuration in my function?

Comment: @FewFlyBy answer to your first question http://stackoverflow.com/a/9166950/1501051

Comment: @FewFlyBy yes you should make a file db_connect.php and include database configuration in it. Then include it where ever you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this below :

```
function logData($action, $values_to_be_saved) {

    if ($action == 'Log in') {
        //Query to save values
    }
}
```

You can call it like :

```
$action = 'Log in'; // Any action you want to call
$values_to_be_saved // Array containing values to be saved like origin, action, user, dt, outcome
logData($action, $values_to_be_saved);
```

Or you can use a switch case for this.

Comment: So it will look like this if I will call it right?
logData("Log in");

Comment: Okay, and do give me a feedback once you try that. Thanks

Comment: Hello, should I include my database configuration in my function?

Comment: You need to create your DB connection before executing your query, you can do that before function call