# Set a cookie without the`domain`, but with `secure` and `httponly`

Tags: php, cookies

PHP's `setcookie` function looks like this:

```
bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )
```

As you can see, `domain` has no standard value, but the following parameters (`httponly` and `secure`) do.

I want both last parameters set to true, but without specifying a domain to bind the cookie to. Is that even possible? Sadly, PHP doesn't allow something like this:

```
setcookie('name', 'value', time()+60, '/', $secure=true, $httponly=true);
```

Also see [this SO question with a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166914/using-default-arguments-in-a-function). Obviously, I cannot change the `setcookie` function.

**EDIT**

Setting the `domain` parameter to `""` or `null` does not work.

Comment: According to the docs, the default for `$domain` is an empty string, so this should work: `setcookie('name', 'value', time()+60, '/', '',true, true);`

Comment: I just tried, it doesn't work. Btw, I'm on a local domain for development, `<projectname>.localhost`, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Have you tried setting the domain parameter as null?

Comment: Doesnt't work either.

Comment: I just tried it with `null` value and it worked on PHP 5.6. The domain is not set in Set-Cookie header and browser (Chrome) sets it then to the current domain.

Answer (score 1):

Testing this on my own development server (PHP 7.3.4), submitting an empty string for the domain works. Submitting **null** may work as well, but with **declare(strict_types=1)** set, PHP generates a message about an incorrect parameter type, string required, NULL supplied.

For example:

```
setcookie('myCookie', 'myCookieData', 0, '/, '', true, true);
```

but not

```
setcookie('myCookie', 'myCookieData', 0, '/, null, true, true);
```

---

However, **setcookie()** allows cookie options to be supplied as an array.

For example:

```
setcookie('myCookie', 'myCookieData',['expires'=>0, 'path'=>'/', 'domain'=>'example.com', 'httponly'=>true, 'secure'=>true];
```

This allows the domain to be omitted from the array, and it's thus not sent to the client:

```
setcookie('myCookie', 'myCookieData',['expires'=>0, 'path'=>'/', 'httponly'=>true, 'secure'=>true];
```

[PHP **setcookie()** page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)