# Fatal error: Call to a member function Function() on boolean

Tags: php, post, form-submit

I wrote simple insert data code but whenever use `!empty($author)` it give me this error `Fatal error: Call to a member function Create() on boolean` but i remove check for `!empty($author)` so then it's work fine. I really don't understand this is giving this error and what mean of it.

Here is my code Comment Class

```
 class Comment extends DatabaseObject{
    // Attributes
    protected static $TableName = 'comment';
    protected static $DBFields = array('id','author','comment','created','photograph_id');
    public $id;
    public $author;
    public $comment;
    public $created;
    public $photograph_id;

    // Create Comment
    public static function Make($photograph_id,$author='Anonymous',$body=''){
        if(!empty($photograph_id) && !empty($author) && !empty($body)){
            $Comment = new Comment();
            $Comment->author = $author;
            $Comment->comment = $body;
            $Comment->photograph_id = (int)$photograph_id;
            $Comment->created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
            return $Comment;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }

    }
    // Find Comment Related Picture
    public static function CommentOfPicture($photograph_id){
        global $db;
        $Comment = static::FindByQuery("SELECT * FROM ".static::$TableName." WHERE `photograph_id`='".$db->EscapeValue($photograph_id)."' ORDER BY created ASC");
        return $Comment;

    }
}
```

Here is my code of Form Submission

```
// Comment Submit
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $Name = trim($_POST['name']);
        $Body = trim($_POST['comment']);
        if(!empty($Body) || !empty($Name)){
            $Comment = Comment::Make($Photo->id,$Name,$Body);
            if($Comment->Create()){
                $Session->MSG("Success: Comment is submit, awaiting for approval");
                RedirectTo("photo.php?id={$Photo->id}");
            }else{
                $Session->MSG("Danger: Something is Wrong");
                RedirectTo("photo.php?id={$Photo->id}");
            }           
        }else{
            $Session->MSG("Danger: Comment is empty");
            RedirectTo("photo.php?id={$Photo->id}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check if `$_POST['name']` has empty string. What are you submitting as `name`?

Comment: I'm submitting author name. `input text` if left it empty so it should be write by default `Anonymous` in it but it's doesn't. it's inserting blank field in it

Answer (score 1):

I think that a relation ( DatabaseObject ) of  **public static function Make** calls the method "Create" on the result of the "Make" method. You're returning FALSE if the condition fails. Then the DatabaseObject calls the method Create on FALSE - with the error! It will be better, if you'll throw an exception instead of returning FALSE or an empty object, if the Create method has to be called.

Comment: Actually buddy it's inserting data perfectly into the database before but when i use check for name like `!empty($author)` it's start giving this error even it's not going to else condition I'm filling all field so it's still reading else condition inside it.

Comment: Then please tell me the result of var_dump( !empty($photograph_id) && !empty($author) && !empty($body) );

Comment: `[id] => 
    [author] => Hamza
    [comment] => I love it
    [created] => 2017-01-06 12:34:27
    [photograph_id] => 26`

Comment: it's working but it's not getting default value of `$author` which is i'm giving on method

Comment: It could be, that the author name is "0" (zero) - empty will set it true as the string "0" is also empty. 

Consider this code:
`$photograph_id = 1;
$author = 'aaaaa';
$body = 'bbbb';

var_dump( !empty($photograph_id) && !empty($author) && !empty($body));

$photograph_id = 1;
$author = '0';
$body = 'bbbb';

var_dump( !empty($photograph_id) && !empty($author) && !empty($body));`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your method signature,

```
public static function Make($photograph_id,$author='Anonymous',$body='')
```

The default argument is going to work like that. If you send `string(0) ""`, the `$author` parameter is going to take empty string value and not `'Anonymous'`

You have few options,

Either change the order of your arguments and make `$author` as last argument ot make it optional if no author name submitted or you can substitue empty author name with `'Anonymous'` taking it as class constant somewhere in the class definition.

Also, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166914/using-default-arguments-in-a-function) might help.