# What to do when one argument doesn't come to function?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

if ( ! function_exists('image_thumb')){
    function image_thumb($courseBanner, $userId){
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $filename_ext = pathinfo($courseBanner, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $course_thumb_Banner = preg_replace('/^(.*)\.' . $filename_ext . '$/', '$1_thumb.' . $filename_ext, $courseBanner);
        $url =  base_url()."private/".$userId."/".$course_thumb_Banner;
        $headers=get_headers($url);
        $is_banner_there  =  stripos($headers[0],"200 OK")?true:false;
        $url = ($is_banner_there)?$url: base_url()."public/images/placeholder.jpg";
        return $url;
    }
}
```

In the above code sometimes $courseBanner doesn't come, so that time I want to send this `base_url()."public/images/placeholder.jpg` How to do?

Comment: It's called setting a default; see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166914/using-default-arguments-in-a-function

Comment: `function image_thumb( $userId, $courseBanner=base_url()."public/images/placeholder.jpg"){`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Default Arguments in a Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166914/using-default-arguments-in-a-function)

Comment: @Kevin so make it optional and write at the end paramter like  function image_thumb($userId, $courseBanner = 'base_url()."public/images/placeholder.jpg'){
 }

Comment: @BunkerBoy below the code  i have line as ternary operator

Comment: @kevin but first your function call and it will demands two argument

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion:**

I think you can set a default value if in case the string (e.g $courseBanner) is empty

**Example:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('image_thumb')){
    function image_thumb($userId, $courseBanner = ''){
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $courseBanner = !empty($courseBanner) ? $courseBanner : base_url()."public/images/placeholder.jpg";
        $filename_ext = pathinfo($courseBanner, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $course_thumb_Banner = preg_replace('/^(.*)\.' . $filename_ext . '$/', '$1_thumb.' . $filename_ext, $courseBanner);
        $url =  base_url()."private/".$userId."/".$course_thumb_Banner;
        $headers=get_headers($url);
        $is_banner_there  =  stripos($headers[0],"200 OK")?true:false;
        return $url;
    }
}
```

This is for reference only so hope this helps

Comment: if only one argument is passed it will throw error as it will take that one argument for `coursebanner`, all optional arguments are put in last

Comment: @eeya make a note that optional parameter always come at the end so please correct your function structure to function image_thumb($userId, $courseBanner = ' ')

Comment: @Bunker Boy, @M A SIDDIQUI .Noted. I'll edit this answer

Comment: @BunkerBoy  but now all courses takes placeholder image.

Comment: @eeya do it fast else i ll will also down vote your answer

Comment: @BunkerBoy . Edited the answer. Sorry about that

Comment: @Kevin . What happens if you've called your method like this? image_thumb($userId, '/sample/url/image');

Comment: its taking only `if (is_string($courseBanner) !== true && strlen($courseBanner) <= 0) {
        $courseBanner = base_url() . "public/images/placeholder.jpg";
    }`

Comment: @BunkerBoy at this point its working correctly `function image_thumb($userId, $courseBanner = ''){
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $courseBanner = !empty($courseBanner) ? $courseBanner : base_url()."public/images/placeholder.jpg";
        
        return $courseBanner;
    }`

Comment: @Kevin tick mark this answer as correct, if it worked for you (y)