# PHP: Prevent default first Function-parameter of been overwrite?

Tags: php, function, parameters

How do I prevent the default first parameters from being overwritten, when second has to be change? I expect the output "SecretPassword", not NULL

```
<?php

  myFunc(NULL,true); //echo NULL not:"SecretPassword"
    
  function myFunc($param1='SecretPassword',$param2=false){
      echo $param1;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Not possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066625/how-would-i-skip-optional-arguments-in-a-function-call

Comment: If you are using PHP 8, you CAN do that using named arguments, they were done for that exact purpose.

Answer (score 1):

you can't, as far as I understand. you would want to write the arguments in reverse order in the function's argument list, so that you can simply leave off the second argument.